# Video is not working in HTML5 on server?

Tags: html, video

I am using firefox 12.0 version and videos are not working in Firefox, chrome and safari too.....

On local videos are working, but on server videos are not working, on server, browser asking for MIME type...

I am using this code for the video embed...

```
<video width="230" height="170" controls="controls">
    <source src="video/main.mp4" type="video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"" />
    <source src="video/main.ogv" type="video/ogg; codecs="dirac, vorbis"" />
</video>
```

Please give me solution on this.

Answer (score 0):

It would help to know what software is serving the video files from the server.

Do you know if that software supports [HTTP Range requests](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.35)? Chrome and Firefox use this for audio and video files to retrieve parts of the file, either to avoid downloading a potentially very large file, or to allow the user to move backwards, forwards, pause and play media. Local files support ranges and seeking, but not all web server software does.